# Prove that the sequence $1+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k+1}{3^{k}+1}$ converges using Cauchy

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

I need some help with a homework question i'm having difficulty with. Here is the question:

"Use the definition of cauchy sequence to prove that the series $\left(1+\frac{2}{3+1}+\frac{3}{9+1}+\cdots+\frac{n+1}{3^{n}+1}\right)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges"

OK so we were shown some examples on how to prove such problems, so the first thing I did was to write it as a summation sequence: $1+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k+1}{3^{k}+1}$

Now I know that in order to prove that it is a Cauchy sequence I should show that for any $ (\epsilon>0) $ There exists an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for any $n,m>N$ and $n>m$  the following occurs: $(|a_{n}-a_{m}|<\epsilon)$

This is where I'm stuck, I just can't seem to find the right N such that it works. Everything I've tried just doesn't seem to work.

Any pushes in the right direction are welcome! 
Thanks!

Comment: I don't know where your $M$ came from in the definition; I think you meant to have $m$ there. Can you give a brute-force estimate for $$\sum_{k=m+1}^n \frac{k+1}{3^k+1}\,?$$ Clearly, there is no closed-form formula for it, so you just need to go back to basics with inequalities (for example, $k\le n$ and can we figure out what $\sum\limits_{k=m+1}^n \dfrac1{3^k}$ is?).

Answer (score 0):

As Ted Shiffin says, $$a_{n}-a_{m} = \sum_{k=m+1}^n \frac{k+1}{3^k+1}$$ but  $3^k+1 \gt 3^k$ so $$a_{n}-a_{m} \lt \sum_{k=m+1}^n \frac{k+1}{3^k} $$ $$= \tfrac14 (2m+5)/3^m - \tfrac14 (2n+5)/3^n $$ $$\lt \tfrac14 (2m+5)/3^m$$ and that decreases rapidly (almost by a factor of $3$ when $m$ increases by $1$) so you can make your Cauchy claim that for any $ \epsilon \gt 0$ there exists an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such as $N = \lceil 1/\epsilon \rceil$ such that for any $n,m \gt N$ you have  $|a_{n}-a_{m}|\lt \epsilon$.

For what it is worth, the actual sum is $\displaystyle 1+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k+1}{3^{k}+1} \approx 2.04384$.